# Поиск в базе данных по времени ввода текста

Tags: php, javascript, поиск

Добрый день. Работаю над одним проектом и столкнулся с такой задачей. При создании заказа в текстовом поле необходимо вписать ФИО клиента, который уже добавлен в базу данных. Так как клиентов более 300 то выпадающий список не подходит. Может есть готовая библиотека на js или php которая реализует подобие подсказок гугла, когда вводишь текст она предлагает выбрать клиента.

Comment: Посоветую [Awesomplete](https://github.com/LeaVerou/awesomplete).

Comment: почему в названии "по времени"? Время как-то участвует в поиске? Может вы имели в виду "во время вода текста"?

Answer (score 1):

Это называется live search или autocomplete
гуглите live search или autocomplete + нужные технологии

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

http://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-live-search-plugins/

Список в данном случае лучше наверное кэшировать на клиенте, обращение к серверу может быть слишком медленным для хорошего UX. При этом в фоне можно проверять, не появилось ли новых.

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!